# Update mysql in select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, ftp

my problem is easy to explain: In my config file from pure-ftp there is only one INSERT-Statement allowed to read the password. It is like this:

```
SELECT password FROM ftpuser WHERE userid = "\L"
```

"\L" is the placeholder for the userid. It works perfectly, but I need to count the access to the ftp-server. There is a field in this table called "accessed". So I need to run this SQL, too:

```
UPDATE ftpuser SET accessed = accessed + 1 WHERE userid = "\L"
```

Is there any way to bring this two statements to one, with "password" as result? Or is there another way to trigger the access from pure-ftp, maybe? Thank you very much!

Sebastian

Comment: Please edit your question to show sample data and the results that you want.  In general, though, you cannot update data *and* return values.  That is different functionality.

Comment: The idea is, that I try to give pure-ftp the functionality to log the last access in the mysql that is used for login-datas. The only way to do is to bring the log-update to the Select-Statement, where the users password is readed. The two statements are only placeholder, they can be complete other statements. But it seems there is no way to "connect" Update and select like I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a question of preserving atomicity, then provided your table is stored using a transactional engine (e.g. InnoDB), you can wrap the whole thing in a transaction with a [locking read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locking-reads.html):

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT password FROM ftpuser WHERE userid = '\L' FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE ftpuser SET accessed = accessed + 1 WHERE userid = '\L';
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Is `FOR UPDATE` really needed? The `UPDATE` statement will place its own locks, and there won't be any issues with concurrency for the `SELECT`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: Doesn't it rather depend on the business logic?  For example, if `accessed` is reset when `password` is changed...